# Оптимизация изображения на php

Tags: php, изображения

Добрый день!

Хочется оптимизировать изображения таким образом, что бы проходить проверку в инструменте гугла PageSpeed Insights

Оптимизировать хочу средствами php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону смотреть?

Comment: ну а вы как думаете?

Comment: https://github.com/psliwa/image-optimizer - готовый оптимизатор изображений на php, еще не плохо склеить все иконки в спрайты, можно как сторонними средствами так и с помощью - https://github.com/namics/php-spriter, если хотите прям все оптимизировать средствами php

Comment: Спасибо, но я никак не могу разобраться - как подключить эту библиотеку? Не нашел ни одного примера, зато есть такой же вопрос без ответа: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926910/how-to-call-php-psliwa-image-optimizer

Comment: Посмотрите функции [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.imagick.php) или [GD](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.image.php)